# Why doesn't this method of solution work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, quadratics

> Solve
>
> $$\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x + 1} - \sqrt{2x^2 - 9x + 4} = 1 \tag1$$

I tried to do the following:

$$(2x^2 - 7x + 1) - (2x^2 - 9x + 4) = 2x-3\tag2$$

Dividing $(2)$ by $(1)$ yields

$$\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x + 1} + \sqrt{2x^2 - 9x + 4} = 2x-3 \tag3$$

Now, adding $(1)$ and $(3)$

$$2\sqrt{2x^2 - 7x + 1} = 2x-4$$

$$\implies \sqrt{2x^2 - 7x + 1} = x-2$$

Squaring both sides and simplifying, yields

$$x^2 - 3x - 3 = 0$$

Solving this quadratic yields an irrational solution. But the solution given in my textbook are $0, 5$ which do work in $(1)$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: 0 isn't answer.

Comment: you divided the two polynomials in (2) by the square roots separately. I.e. $\frac{(2x^2-7x+1)-(2x^2-9x+4)}{\sqrt{2x^2-7x+1}-\sqrt{2x^2-9x+4}} \neq \sqrt{2x^2-7x+1}+\sqrt{2x^2-9x+4}$

Comment: @Hrodelbert: Yes, we can factorize the above using the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ then cancel the common terms

Comment: @Panda: Yes it is. $\sqrt{1} - \sqrt{4} = (-1) - (-2) = 1$

Comment: @Gerard, Ah, very nice, I was too quick to judge. Sorry! Could you elaborate further on choosing negative values for your square root, as in your answer to Panda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add (1) and (3), the right side should be $2x-2$.  Then it simplifies to $x^2 - 5x = 0$ which has the solutions 0 and 5.

Comment: Oh, yes of course! Silly me.

Comment: As Panda already said, $0$ is not an answer to the original equation. Plugging in $0$ yields $-1$ for the left-hand side.